# How can I search for misspelled words on my index?

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, search

I'm building a monitoring web app that follows this workflow:

- A brand's (volvo, bmw, etc) social account, facebook for this example, is linked to the app and all the info (comments, reactions, posts) is retrieved and saved to a local DB.
- Stats are generated and displayed on an internal dashboard.
- Users can then search from this dashboard for posts or comments containing certain words.

I am using Select2 on the search form and only allowing users to search for individual words ie. [bad, car, service].

A simple implementation using mySQL search has already been deployed and I am since working with Elastic Search for a better solution.

So my question is:

On the local database I have 5 records containing:

- "This car is really awful"
- "This car is really awfeul"
- "This car is really waful"
- "This car is really awfful"
- "This car is really awfull"

How can I get all this records back when the user searches for "awful"

I have been trying with the phrase suggest example on their [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-phrase.html) without any luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, take a look on [fuzziness](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#fuzziness) or [fuzzy query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html). Should be helpful for you.

You can use [`match` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-fuzziness) for with `fuzziness = AUTO`:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "match" : {
      "your_field_name" : {
        "query" : "awful",
        "fuzziness": "AUTO"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

if `AUTO` is not sufficient you can specify the param base on [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#fuzziness).